# php case argument for loop

Tags: php, loops, arguments, case

I need some help writing loops and passing arguments to functions.

```
switch ( $action ) {
  case 'listItemTypeOne':
    listItems(TypeOne);
    break;
  case 'newItemTypeOne':
    newItem(TypeOne);
    break;
  case 'deleteItemTypeOne':
    deleteItem(TypeOne);
    break;
  case 'listItemTypeTwo':
    listItems(TypeTwo);
    break;
  case 'newItemTypeTwo':
    newItem(TypeTwo);
    break;
  case 'deleteItemTypeOne':
    deleteItem(TypeTwo);
    break;
  default: 
    listItems(TypeOne);
}
```

I should mention that these types represent a class.
Now here is that part which I cannot yet comprehend

```
function listItem(Type)
   $results = array();
   $data = TypeClass::getList();
   $results[Type] = $data['results'];
}

function newItem(Type) {
  $results = array();
  $type = new TypeClass;
  $type->storeFormValues( $_POST );
  $type->insert();
}
function deleteItem(Type) {
  $type->delete();
}
```

What would i need to do to pass the item type to the functions and not make duplicate functions? Some kind of loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function listItems($Type){
   $results = array();
   swith($Type){
     case 'TypeOne':
       $data = TypeOne::getList();
       break;
     case 'TypeTwo':
       $data = TypeTwo::getList();
       break;
   }
   $results[$Type] = $data['results'];
}
```